# Content sent to API is truncated

Tags: xml, asp.net-web-api, put, postman

I'm using PostMan to re-send (Xml) content to a webAPI method. Unfortunately the Xml content is being truncated at the point where `&gt;` is being specified in the string (the xml contains an attribute that has xml already url encoded)

I cannot change the format of the xml, as it's already in use from the application as I'm just pulling the value from a table in sql, and reposting it to the api for testing purposes. and I need to be able to pull the data as-is, and repost it to the api via PostMan with very little effort (I may have to do this repeatedly with different data).

The API signature is:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody]string userDataSetString, [FromUri(Name = "V")]string apiVersion)
```

And the data this is what I have in PostMan:

[image: Postman Settings]

When I execute this against the API, the `userDataSetString` parameter has:

```
<Test Value="
```

Is there something I need to add to the header to allow it to cope with this?

**EDIT** As an alternative, I will also take any answer that has me store the xml in a file, and attach it in postman for sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out that the problem was due to the presence of `&` in the code.

Prior to inserting my data into the Postman RAW text window, I needed to do a global replace on & with `%26`

**Before**

```
=<Test Value="&gt;Data"></Test>
```

**After**

```
=<Test Value="%26gt;Data"></Test>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HttpRequestMessage`:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromUri(Name = "V")]string apiVersion)
{
    var xml = request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    ...
    return new HttpResponseMessage();
}
```

And post with the next header:

```
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and next body (without '=' character at the begining)

```
<Test Value="&gt;Data"></Test>
```